# Gitlab: Is it possible to filter merge requests by target branch?

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab CE, one can filter Merge Requests on Author, Assignee, Milestones and Labels. We cannot find a way to filter the search by Target Branch. Are we missing how this is done, or is that feature not available?

In Github, this is done by entering `base:x` where x is the branch to filter by under Pull Requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to filter merge requests by target branch is now implemented directly in GitLab via https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/33831 since about 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not yet possible to filter Merge Requests by the destination branch, although it is an open feature proposal in [issue 22135](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22135). I apologize that this may not be the answer you were hoping for.

Please feel free to mark your support for the proposal, discuss any ideas, or even submit a merge request if you’d like to do so.  You can do any of these from the [issue page](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22135) and I encourage you to lend your voice to the development of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, here's how!

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/mr/list.md

```
glab mr list --target-branch=trunk
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I did not know about glab before. Although not ideal as it requires to 1 - install an extra app, 2 - use the cli  for this instead of the browser.